# How to make popup login and register from index.php to work and to parse data in mysql

Tags: php, ajax, forms, popup, modal-dialog

I have:
Index.php, login.php, register.php

In index.php I have modal popup and I want to user can login and register from popup.

I try with ajax but not working.
Here is my code:
ajax.php:

```
 function validLogin(){
  var email=$('.email').val();
  var password=$('.password').val();
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "sign-in.inc",
     data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,
      success: function(html){
           if(html=='true'){
            alert ("Correct");
          }
          else{
              alert ("Wrong");
          }
}
  });
```

}

and here is popup form :

```
<div id="login">
    <form class="form login-form" name="login-popup" >
        <a class="btn-facebook" href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
</span><span>Login with Facebook</span></a>
        <a class="btn-google" href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
</span>
        <span>Login with Google</span></a>
        <p class="fieldset">
            <label class="image-replace email icon-log" for="signin-email">E-mail</label>
            <input class="full-width has-padding has-border email" id="signin-email" name="email-login" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" required>
            <span class="error_box"></span>
          </p>
          <p class="fieldset">
            <label class="image-replace password" for="signin-password">Password</label>
            <input class="full-width has-padding has-border password" id="signin-password"  type="password"  placeholder="Password"
            name="password" required>
            <a href="#0" class="hide-password">Show</a>
            <span class="error-message"></span>
          </p>
          <p class="fieldset">
            <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" checked>
            <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
          </p>
          <p class="fieldset">
            <input class="full-width orange" id="login-submit" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="validLogin()" value="Login">
          </p>
        </form>
        <p class="form-bottom-message"><a href="#0">Forgot your password?</a></p>
        <!-- <a href="#0" class="close-form">Close</a> -->
      </div>
```

Comment: can you define for us, *"not working"*?

Comment: The first issue I see is that you have `email` and `password` class for more than 1 input.

Comment: ...right ^ use an id.

Comment: Second, you can't POST to 'sign-in.inc', unless you have *.inc mapped to PHP in your Web server. I doubt you do. You will want to post to a *.php or some file that can handle the post.

Comment: "sign-in.inc" ?? What is this ?

Comment: Third, you cross over from `email` variable, to `username` in your data. So you're sending a `NULL` through since `username` would be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would advise moving your JQuery to using IDs for selectors and not Classes. Second, your `url` doesn't look right. Unless you have `.inc` being handled or mapped on your server, this will not be able to process the request. Take a look:

```
function validLogin(){
    var email = $('#signin-email').val();
    var password = $('#signin-password').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sign-in.php",
        data: "name="+email+"&pwd="+password,
        success: function(html){
            if(html=='true'){
                alert ("Correct");
            } else {
                alert ("Wrong");
            }
        }
    });
}
```